# What could someone do if they got hold of my Facebook App Id & Secret?

Tags: facebook, key

Even if I accidentally published my Fb App Id and Secret Key, how could anyone harm my app if they have no access to my App Dashboard?

Comment: maybe change your secret key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all even if you did this, which you should never ever do, you should consider changing your App Secret immediately without further delay.

Secondly, As your question asks, for starters they can do a **lot of damage** to people associated with your application starting with you.

- Though they won't have user access token for your account but they can know the permissions you have provided the application, and if you have provided `publish_stream` permission, which many people who post their App Secret on Stack Overflow do, anyone can **Post** things on your wall on your behalf. Which I would consider a major serious issue.
- They can create Migrations
- Create demographic restrictions on an app
- Set properties for an app as described in Application [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/)
- Ban Users from your application
- And do many other things that just requires App Access Token as described in the Application's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/)
- Moreover if your app behavior is under scrutiny then, maybe it would directly affect the Facebook account that created the application which directly in many cases will be you.

So please safeguard your App Secret always to build Apps that Users can trust.